# Valgrind found memleak for pointer of pointer

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I study C.
I'm have simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


unsigned
my_fopen(FILE **fp, const char *file_name)
{
    *fp = fopen(file_name, "a"); // memleak here
    if (!*fp) {
        printf("Can't fopen file: %s\n", file_name);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // begin only for -Wall -Werror -Wextra
    int p = 0;
    printf("Cnt: %d\n", argc);
    while (p < argc) {
        printf("Arg %d: %s\n", p, argv[p]);
        p += 1;
    }
    // end only for -Wall -Werror -Wextra

    FILE *my_fp;
    my_fopen(&my_fp, "./test.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind (valgrind -v --track-origins=yes --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full ./test) says:

```
==960== HEAP SUMMARY:
==960==   in use at exit: 568 bytes in 1 blocks
==960==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 568 bytes allocated
```

1) Why?
2) How to fix it?

Comment: Well, i don't see any matching `fclose()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Not exactly.. I will go with John's answer. You can just go ahead as we see the purpose of the `my_fopen()` is to open the file stream and access it in the `main()`

Comment: @Gopi I don't see how the usage of the file _justifies_ not performing `fclose()` before returning from `main()`. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Isn't said by standard that after returning from `main()` all open files get closed with a preseding `fflush()` or equalbehaving? So ofc this looks nasty, but is it really needed?

Comment: @Zaibis but the valgrind will report that as _possible_ leak, right ? [still reachable], IMO, if a file has been _opened_ by me, it _should_ be _closed_ by myself. :-)

Comment: Of course, just wasn't sure about anymore.

Answer (score 1):

you are opening a file but not closing the file, 
before returning from main. you can do

```
if ( 0 != my_fp )
  fclose(my_fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem here is not closing the file pointer before leaving `main()`.

Just add

```
if (my_fp)
fclose(my_fp);
```

before `return 0;` in `main()`.